# Replace string in mysql- href

Tags: mysql, replace

Good day to all!
How can I change, in mysql db, something like
href="/ with href="http://something/. I have problems with ".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to deal with the double quotes I think you have 2 easy options:

1) Wrap them in single quotes like this:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_field = 'href="http://mysite...something/'
WHERE my_field = 'href="http:/';
```

2) Escape them with backslashes like this:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_field = "href=\"http://example.com/\""
WHERE my_field = "href=\"http:/";
```

Comment: You both helped me:

UPDATE my_table SET my_field=REPLACE(my_field,'href="/','href="mysite...something') Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table SET column=REPLACE(column,'oldstring','newstring')
```